# How to get the output when querying InfluxDB in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

c0="show databases"
c1="select count(grade1) from INFO where grade2>60;"
i=0
( while((i++<5))
do
  echo ${c1} 
done ) | influx -precision rfc3339 -port 50010 -database Ttest10w8
```

When I run this script, I get the output in command line as below:

```
name: INFO
time                 count
----                 -----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 42000
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 43007
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 44010
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 45015
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 46015
```

I want to get all the numbers in `count`.

That is I want to get all the numbers(`42000`,`43007`,`44010`,`45015`) when running the script, and then I will use these numbers to do something else after the `while` loop ended.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a while loop for this.

To print `c1` four times:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$c1"{,,,}
```

Or, to print `c1` `n` times:

```
printf "%.0s${c1//%/%%}\n" $(seq n)
```

To get contents of the `count` column:

```
awk 'NR>3{print $2}'
```

To read output into an array:

```
readarray my_array
```

Bring them together:

```sh
readarray my_array < <( printf '%s\n' "$c1"{,,,} | influx args | awk 'NR>3{print $2}' )
```

Comment: What does the 'NR>3' mean in `awk 'NR>3{print $2}'` ?

Comment: @waveschj it means *if line number is greater than 3, print second column*

Answer (score 0):

You can filter only the data lines (starting with a digit) with `grep`, print the second column with `awk` and insert them into an array.

```
arr=();
( while((i++<5))
do
   entry=$(echo ${c1} | grep -P "^\d" | awk '{print $2}')
   arr+=($entry) 
done ) ...
echo ${arr[@]}
```

Comment: You don't need grep here. `awk '/^[0-9]/{print $2}'` does the same.

Comment: @oguzismail that was in fact an edit that I, wrongly, accepted: arr=$(...)